# How can you get React Native logging to appear in the iPhone console (instead/in addition to the Xcode console)

Tags: react-native

If you have a `console.log("some logging)` code line in a React Native app (i.e. in Javascript) and run the app on an iPhone then you can see the logging appear inside what I'm going to call the Xcode console, or if you shake the app then in a browser.

However you cannot see that logging appear in what I'm going to call the iPhone console.

My question is - is there a way of adding logging to React Native code where the output is visible in the iPhone console in addition to the Xcode console.

Further information on what I mean by iPhone console:
If you interactively run an iOS app using Xcode, then there is a logging console displayed. What I am terming here as the Xcode console.

But if from within Xcode you choose the menu option Window | Devices and Simulators | Open Console" Then you can see full iPhone logging (i.e. what the system is logging in addition to what your app is logging.
This is what I'm calling the iPhone console.
Viewing it via XCode is not the only way of viewing or obtaining the iPhone logs, there are other ways too.

When you do iPhone native development and use `NSLog()` then it will log to both the Xcode console and the iPhone console, however when logging using React Native `console.log()` the logging only appears in the Xcode console.
I want logging code added to React Native Javascript code to additionally appear in the iPhone console.

Comment: Would really love to know how to do this for testing in TestFlight for those bugs that appear magically only in TestFlight.

Answer (score 2):

First shake your Iphone then you can see this screen.

[image]

Then click Debug JS remotely button.

After you might see React Native Debugger page like this.

[image]

And then open your inspector[f12], and go to console tab debug it! :)

Comment: Thanks but the question was how to make logging appear in the iPhone console.

Comment: @Gruntcakes can you give an example of `iPhone console`? so I can understand you

Comment: I rewrote the question, hopefully its clearer.

Comment: @Gruntcakes can you add an example screenshot of `iPhone console` so I can check if it possible or not

Comment: Useful, but doesn't answer the question as posed. Specifically, this won't work for a release build sans debugger, e. g. for an end user.